# What is the difference between the IP address needed for ssh, and the IP address that is displayed once inside the server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ip, ping, host

When I `ssh` into my server, I issue the following command:

`ssh <username>@<ip-of-server>`

Then, when I get in, I see the following as my prompt:

`<username>@ip-<different-ip-address>:`

When I try `echo $PS1` in the server, then I see the following:

`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$`, which tells me that the host must be different.  Why are these not the same:  ip and host?

The reason I ask is because, I can access the  just fine by ssh-ing, but I cannot ping it:

`ping <ip-of-server>`  ... results in 100% losses.

So, I thought maybe I should ping the other ip, however:

`ping ip-<different-ip-address>`  ... also results in 100% losses.

How is it possible to not be able to ping, yet I can still log in?

Comment: probably `<ip-of-server>` is a public ip and `<different-ip-address>` is private

Comment: how to test that though?

Comment: just check `<different-ip-address>` range, if is private should b:  `From 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255.
From 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255.
From 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private IP is internal to AWS which is 10.x.x.x

You can also check that by invoking

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`

within your instance which gets that info from the metadata server.

Public IP (if assigned) is the external IP. You can get the same from metadata server. Try:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
```

If your shell prompt is an issue, you can set the prompt after querying the public IP.

Answer (score 1):

ip-of-server is probably the public ip of the server. different-ip-address is probably the private ip of the server.

pings will not go through from the outside unless you enable ICMP traffic through the Security group the you've set for your instance.

It's possible to log in because the port used for SSH is open (TCP 22) in the Security group, while ICMP is not open (ICMP).